# Unity3D Load Level async progress strange behaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a scene asynchronously so I can have a nice progress bar and I found that the returned AsyncOperation.progress stops at 0.9. I don't have a problem with that but what is happening is that after that, it takes up to 50s to load the scene and that doesn't show on the progress. After deleting some objects I found that there is 1 (the main scene object) that is causing this delay.

My question is, is there any way to load this object in the first 90% of the load (which is happening super fast right now - 1s)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems it all comes to the substances I was using. It's really strange for me because I explicity check all of them as "bake and discard substance" which seems to do nothing. After baking all the textures and switch from substance to texture in the material the loading came down from 42s to 1s

Answer (score 3):

If this GameObject is inside the scene, it is loaded with the scene. The problem you have is with the all script logic inside the scene. The loading thread actually finished, but the scripts, instantieting etc., takes all device resources and it looks like stuck at 90%.

To solve it I think you should delay all scripts executions on Awake or Start methods. That should help, but still all the time needed on particular device to execute scripts will take all CPU, and will look like stuck again.

Comment: So all that time is for instantiating that particular object?

Comment: I think that not instatiating (this is done in the async thread) but executon of its scripts.

Comment: this object doesn't have scripts. And when I delete it from the scene it loads pretty fast - 2s overall

Comment: I see your answer. So it wasnt scripts but substances, anyway after loading all GameObjects the CPU was occupied by "something". Cheers